# %20d %20s %20u in link Python 3.5

Tags: python, hyperlink, web-scraping, percentage

I am trying to web scrape some Tweets from this url using Python 3.5

`url = "https://twitter.com/search?l=en&q=ecb%20draghi%20since%3A2012-09-01%20until%3A2012-09-02&src=typd"`

My problem is that %20d %20s %20u are already encoded in Python 3.5, so my code does not run on this url. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Best

Comment: The link you provided is already a working one with python 3.5. I found no problem to make use of your provided link.

Answer (score 0):

%20 is the URL encoding for space (0x20 being space's ASCII code). Just replace all those %20 by spaces and everything will likely work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `urllib2.unquote()` in python 2 or `urllib.request.unquote()` in python 3 to decode the url.

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://twitter.com/search?l=enq=ecb%20draghi%20since%3A2012-09-01%20until%3A2012-09-02&src=typd"
decoded_url = urllib.request.unquote(url)
print(decoded_url)
```

Answer (score 0):

it is working fine in MY PC, %20  is for space only. URLs cannot contain spaces.

Read from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)

URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.